# Can't sign APK because of third party library

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed-apk, contactpicker

This is my first app publication. The project is working fine in the development side, but I am facing a problem during **signing APK**.

[image]

**Included library** in the app of `com.1gravity:android-contactpicker`

and facing problem during **signing apk** only.

error coming

> Error:(30, 44) error: package com.onegravity.contactpicker.contact
>   does not exist

and

> Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the
>   errors in the 'Messages' view.

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.mymatatu'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    debugCompile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

Comment: please share your proguard content

Comment: Haven't you missed adding compile 'com.1gravity:android-contactpicker:1.3.2' in dependencies in your build.gradle file?

Comment: where i can find out proguard content please?

Comment: @Jordan after adding dependency .I have done some change in external library. They all are not working ....

Comment: @khaleel_jageer are you taking about this file `proguard-rules.pro`. It is empty . Every thing in it is commenting ...

Comment: You are getting compilation error. Are you able to build in release (not debug) mode?

Comment: @user1209216 project is working in mobile . but facing problem during signing apk or in releasing .....

Comment: First try to switch to release, then clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your gradle file change this

```
debugCompile project(':library')
```

line into

```
compile project(':library')
```